# Filesystem commands hangs only on a specific file in a directory

Tags: linux, shell, virtual-machine, nfs

I have a filesytem on a VM mounted via NFS. This issue is replicated on the VM itself, so I no longer think it is related to NFS.

The filesystem has the format:

```
/
  dir_a
    file_a
    file_b
    ...
    special.csv
  dir_b
    file_a
    file_b
    ...
    special.csv
```

These files under each directory written at roughly the same time, with `special.csv` being written last. `special.csv` is written as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.Dataframe()
# populate small dataframe (~30 rows of 5 columns of ints/doubles and 1 column of 60char str)
hidden_path = os.path.join(base_dir, '.special.csv')
actual_path = os.path.join(base_dir, 'special.csv')
df.to_csv(hidden_path, index=False)
os.replace(hidden_path, actual_path)
```

When running `rm -rf dir_a`, I noticed it was taking much longer than expected (on the order of magnitude of minutes for a directory with ~30 files of total size ~5gb). Upon further investigation it was found that all the other files in the directory get removed fairly immediately except for the `special.csv` file.

When running `strace -T rm -Rf special.csv` it was found that the `unlinkat` syscall was taking `~89s` to complete.

I'm not sure why the behavior would be different for the `special.csv` file compared to the other files in the directory, especially since the other files in the directory are created in a similar manner (in regards to the `os.replace`). The only difference I can think of is that the other files are touched before written to, and they are written using `pyarrow`.

It also seems like any sort of modification or deletion to the `special.csv` takes magnitudes longer e.g. `touch special.csv` can take over a minute. However, if I `touch special.csv` and then `rm special.csv`, only the `touch special.csv` takes a long time, the `rm special.csv` is instantaneous. Not sure if this has something to do with the disk cache.

**EDIT:**
The storage medium is a linux file system mount and not a NAS. Root cause was not determined, but a reboot of the storage medium seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look closely at the NAS you are connecting to with the NFS. Does it have a "trash" capability? Is it turned on?

The NFS mount does not actually delete the files, it requests from the remote system to delete them. And the NAS (most likely) moves these big files into trash, so NAS can later restore it back if requested. The remote system reports back to your NFS that files are deleted, but they are actually in the process at this moment.

Comment: I can’t check at the moment, but wanted to clarify the file that takes a long time to remove also takes a long time to modify e.g. touch. It’s also a very small file <~1kb

Comment: Long modification time can also mean dying harddrives in the NAS.

Comment: Wouldn’t that apply to all files in the directory and not a specific one?

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be that just a section of HDD went bad and NAS is trying to fix it with the RAID capabilities. Or the writing operation can go slow, while reading is fine. There are tons of variations! But they all come to NAS's problems.

Comment: I’ve added more detail to my post, the filesystem is on a VM and the issue is replicated on the VM itself so it is probably not NFS related, but that does not rule out the NAS

Comment: I've also added another detail where modification of the file, e.g. `touch` and then deletion does not take a long time. So the initial `touch` takes a while, but the `rm` afterwards does not

Comment: backing medium is not a NAS and just a regular linux file server. A reboot seems to have fixed the issue